# a curved arrow on a path

Tags: arrows

I don't know why,  but the last four commands (\draw[ultra thick...) don't work in the following codes (they shift the figure to the left of the page).

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

    \draw[thick,->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \draw[thick,->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);

    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(-157:0.75)] 2, 1.5) arc (-157:150.5:0.75cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(65:0.75)] -1, 0.5) arc (65:405:0.75cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(-150:1.25)] 2, 1.5) arc (-150:180:1.25cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(13:1.25)] -1, 0.5) arc (13:365:1.25cm);

    \draw[ultra thick] (1.36,1.88) -- (-0.7,1.18);
    \draw[ultra thick] (-0.47,1.03) -- (0.77,1.47);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0.20,0.80) -- (1.33,1.22);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0.24,0.60) -- (0.94,0.87);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}] (1.36,1.88) -- 
    (-0.7,1.18);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  (-0.47,1.03) 
    -- (0.77,1.47);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  (0.20,0.80) 
    -- (1.33,1.22);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrowreversed{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  
    (0.24,0.60) -- (0.94,0.87);

    \draw[fill] (-0.47,1.03) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.24,0.60) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (1.36,1.89) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (-0.7,1.19) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.21,0.81) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (1.30,1.21) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.92,0.86) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.75,1.47) circle (0.04);

    \node at (-1,0.5) {$\times$};
    \node at (-1,0.3) {$r_{2}$};
    \node at (2,1.5) {$\times$};
    \node at (2,1.3) {$r_{1}$};

    \draw[ultra thick,{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}-]($(135,0.75)+(2,1.5)$) 
     arc (135:90:0.75);
    \draw[ultra thick,{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}-]($(135,1.25)+(2,1.5)$) 
     arc (135:90:1.25);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}]($(270,0.75)+(-1,0.5)$) 
     arc (270:315:0.75);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}]($(270,1.25)+(-1,0.5)$) 
     arc (270:315:1.25);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Pochhammer contour, another path used for the integral 
     representation of confluent hypergeometric functions}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable! And please add an screenshot to your qustion and mark there the wanted changes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the coordinates down there are written as Cartesian but probably should be polar. I also stress that this is not a Pochhammer contour. The monodromies do not cancel, but they add up.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

    \draw[thick,->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \draw[thick,->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);

    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(-157:0.75)] 2, 1.5) arc (-157:150.5:0.75cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(65:0.75)] -1, 0.5) arc (65:405:0.75cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(-150:1.25)] 2, 1.5) arc (-150:180:1.25cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift=(13:1.25)] -1, 0.5) arc (13:365:1.25cm);

    \draw[ultra thick] (1.36,1.88) -- (-0.7,1.18);
    \draw[ultra thick] (-0.47,1.03) -- (0.77,1.47);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0.20,0.80) -- (1.33,1.22);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0.24,0.60) -- (0.94,0.87);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}] (1.36,1.88) -- 
    (-0.7,1.18);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  (-0.47,1.03) 
    -- (0.77,1.47);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  (0.20,0.80) 
    -- (1.33,1.22);

    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrowreversed{latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]  
    (0.24,0.60) -- (0.94,0.87);

    \draw[fill] (-0.47,1.03) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.24,0.60) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (1.36,1.89) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (-0.7,1.19) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.21,0.81) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (1.30,1.21) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.92,0.86) circle (0.04);
    \draw[fill] (0.75,1.47) circle (0.04);

    \node at (-1,0.5) {$\times$};
    \node at (-1,0.3) {$r_{2}$};
    \node at (2,1.5) {$\times$};
    \node at (2,1.3) {$r_{1}$};

    \draw[ultra thick,{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}-]($(135:0.75)+(2,1.5)$) 
     arc (135:90:0.75);
    \draw[ultra thick,{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}-]($(135:1.25)+(2,1.5)$) 
     arc (135:90:1.25);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}]($(270:0.75)+(-1,0.5)$) 
     arc (270:315:0.75);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{latex[length=0.3cm, bend]}]($(270:1.25)+(-1,0.5)$) 
     arc (270:315:1.25);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]